# Syncfusion integration with flutter for web

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I tried to use flutter for web with syncfusion library. I ran into compilation issues. Has anyone tried that integration ?

I used flutter channel beta (since my development was targeted for web and mobile both)

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to replicate your scenario, unfortunately, we are not able to replicate any compilation issues while running on the web. So, kindly please make sure that you are using the current version of our chart widget [18.1.46](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/versions/18.1.46). If you are not using the current version, please upgrade to the current version and try to replicate the issues and revert us with more information on the compilation issues and a sample attachment would be appreciable so that it will be helpful in providing the solution sooner.

And also, please follow the instruction in the link below to build the flutter application in the web.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web.

**Note:** I work for Syncfusion